# SanDisk Extreme external SSD stopped being listed by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, external-hard-drive

The drive used to work (up to yesterday). Now when I plug in the drive I hear the regular Windows 10 sound, but the drive doesn't show up in any listing - including in Disk Management (!). When I unplug it, I hear the normal Windows 10 sound.

Sandisk Extreme 500GB external SSD, connects via USB.

Comment: Have you tried another machine?  Have you tried creating a new user?  External SSDs do not have an unlimited lifespan, it's entirely possible, the drive is simply dead.

Comment: I don't have another computer.  I could create a new user.  The SSD is four months old.  And it's been connected to the computer maybe 15 times - about 4 of those for full days (with little use), the rest for 2-3 hours at a time.  It's been used very little.

Comment: Also try a different USB port

Comment: I tried a different USB port.

Comment: This is a clean install of Windows 10 1909, a few days old, and I'm getting an error trying to add a user account.  Doing it through settings, nothing happens.  Doing it from a command prompt, "net user TempUser /add" , returns "The user or group account specified cannot be found. / The user was successfully created but could not be added to the USERS local group. / More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3774.

Comment: Other USB devices are working.

Comment: I posted a new question about the problem creating a new user account: https://superuser.com/questions/1589586/cant-add-additional-users-to-clean-install-of-windows-10-1909

Comment: Instead of creating a new user, which is an entirely different problem, enable the built-in Administration and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved when I resolved the problem of not being able to add a new user account (a suggestion here was to try a different user account).

I resolved the account creation problem by executing:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
SFC /SCANNOW
```

This also solved the problem of the SSD not being detected/listed.