# Can't add additional users to clean install of Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

This is a clean install of Windows 10 1909 - a few days old.

When I try to add a user account through settings, nothing happens.  The window just stays there, with no new account showing.

When I try using a command prompt, this happens:

```
C:\>net user Test3 /add
The user or group account specified cannot be found.

The user was successfully created but could not be added
to the USERS local group.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3774.

C:>NET HELPMSG 3774

The user was successfully created but could not be added
to the USERS local group.
```

A full Malewarebytes scan found nothing.
Lenovo Ideapad 330s

Comment: Issues like you describe could be explained by a pending Windows Update.  Is that the case?

Comment: No. (That is not the case - need 12 characters to comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have gone wrong with the install. Try the first level repair to see if that corrects the issue.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

dism.exe  /online   /cleanup-image   /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe   /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC  /SCANNOW

Allow to complete, restart and test. If there are updates pending, they will occur at this time.

Also (it may not be related), run the Lenovo Driver update app and update all drivers.

If you continue to have issues with your install, contact Lenovo Support with your model and serial number and ask them to send you the Recovery USB.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. I amended my answer to include contacting Lenovo for a Recovery USB.

Comment: **You don’t have to contact Lenovo for a recovery USB**. That will likely cost you money for something that is free

Comment: Lenovo Recovery USB keys include all drivers and may be a good investment now and in the future. I have them for all my Lenovo machines. It is an option that I post.

Comment: I updated the Lenovo drivers online right after the install, using my laptops serial number.  They show you what specific drivers need updated.

Comment: Complete. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.  (I'm afraid to reboot right now - due to the user account issue.)

Comment: I suggest your installation did not proceed properly (else I do not think these problems would occur). There I do suggest installing again with the Lenovo Recovery USB. Call them (call Support) and they may allow you to download the USB Key.

Comment: Upon reboot, the account I tried to create was listed, and I logged into it.  From there I can create user accounts without issue.  Logging back into the original user account, there's still an issue creating users, but it's partially resolved.  I can create an account from the command prompt. When I try to create an account from settings, and select "I don't have the user info" (to create an account without associating a Microsoft e-mail account), I get "Something went wrong / Cancel / Retry.  With the new account, there were no issues like this.

Comment: Something went wrong with your original profile.  Make a new local account, make it a member of Administrators, log into it and delete the other accounts.  Then you can, if you wish, make this new local account your Microsoft Account.